# How to highlight a row in DATATABLE from Leaflet map marker info?

Tags: javascript, datatables, leaflet

The code below highlights a row in a table when the mouse cursor is over a map marker.
This works, but not for all map markers, although there are values in the log.
I've tried using the trim() function on marker.on, but that's clearly not the problem. What could be the problem?

now the selection is like this

```
AAA no
BBB Yes
CCC no
DDD Yes
FFF-no
```

Mapscript

```
 <script>
      function createmaprker(dataArray) {
        var map = L.map('viewmap').setView([51.56, -0.12], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
          var marker = L.marker([dataArray[i][5], dataArray[i][6]]).addTo(map);
          marker.bindPopup("Book: " + dataArray[i][2] + "<br>" + "Pages: " + dataArray[i][3]);
    
          marker.on("mouseover", function(e) {
            var popup = e.target.getPopup();
            
            var content = popup.getContent();
           
            var tr = $("#data-table").find("td").filter(function() {
    
              return $(this).text() == content.split("<br>")[0].split(": ")[1];
               
            }).closest("tr");
    
    
            tr.addClass("highlight");
          });
    
    
          marker.on("mouseout", function(e) {
            var popup = e.target.getPopup();
            var content = popup.getContent();
            var tr = $("#data-table").find("td").filter(function() {
              return $(this).text() == content.split("<br>")[0].split(": ")[1];
            }).closest("tr");
    
            tr.removeClass("highlight");
          });
    
         
    
          
        }
      }
    </script>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

function getData() {

 var values=[['111', '1111', 'AAA', '752', 'Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.11'], ['222', '5555', 'BBB',' 1040', 'Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.10'], ['333', '777','CCC', '846', 'Hardcover', '51.565', '-0.11'], ['444', '888', 'DDD','258','Paperback', '51.56', '-0.12'], ['555', '555',' FFF',' 789','Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.13']]
return values;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}
```

Scriptdata

```
<script>

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
  function showData(dataArray){
    console.log(dataArray);

    createmaprker(dataArray);

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        columns: [
          {"title":"Rating"},
          {"title":"Reviews"},
          {"title":"Book"},
          {"title":"Pages"},
          {"title":"Type"},
          {"title":"Longitude"},
          {"title":"Latitude"},
        ]
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

  <?!= include('Scriptdata'); ?>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

    }
    #viewmap {
      width: 60%;
      height: 60vh;
      left: 0%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #text {
      font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }


  .highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
 




  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="viewmap"></div>

  <?!= include('Mapscript'); ?>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the DataTables zebra-striping style is interfering with your attempts to highlight the rows with dark grey stripes.

One fix for this is to remove `table-striped` from your HTML table definition.

If you want to keep your zebra striping, you will need to add `!important` to your highlighting style:

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

You can see an example of this in the official DataTables documentation: [Highlighting rows and columns](https://datatables.net/examples/api/highlight.html).

Click on the "CSS" tab on that page to see the style example they are using.

---

There is also a small typo in the data set here: `' FFF'` - note that extra space before the first `F`.